# Adding elements from a single column in a 2D list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a function that will find the sum of the elements of one column of a 2D list, but only the one specific column. I can find plenty of examples of how to find the sum for every column in the list, but not one that only gives me the one specific column. And the list has to be from a different function.

```
def sumColumn(matrix, columnIndex):
(No idea what on earth to put here...)
return total
```

Answer (score 1):

For heavy matrix work it is recommended to use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> matrix = [[0, 2, 0], 
              [0, 1, 0]]
>>> columnIndex = 1     # 1 means the second(middle) column
>>> np.array(matrix)[:, columnIndex].sum()
3
```

In pure Python:

```
sum(row[columnIndex] for row in matrix)
```

Comment: (@OP) And, if you will do a lot of math with your matrices, NumPy is generally better than lists-of-lists because of sheer performance and awesome indexing, broadcasting and matrix math operations.

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
sum_column = lambda l, i: sum(x[i] for x in l)
```

More readable, almost English:

```
def sum_column(matrix, index):
    return sum(line[index] for line in matrix)
```